# Dundas DashBoards

Tags: dundas

Hi I am using Dundas dashboards that has different tabs and when we select one of the tabs, the tabs color must be changed such that it can be shown that it is the active tab.  How can I do this??

I am using Dundas Dashboards 2.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you've created the tabs, since there is no out-of-the-box tab control in Dundas Dashboard.

Assuming there is some background property of the "tab", you could change it using DundasScript in the Click interaction which focuses the new tab.